# PyTables said missing, preveting VITables to be installed

Tags: python, pytables

PyTables is one of the requirements to install [VITables](http://vitables.org/index.html) on Windows .
I checked the installation with Table.test and all looks good. The test returns:

---

tables.test() 
PyTables version:  2.3.1 
HDF5 version:      1.8.8 
NumPy version:     1.6.1 
Numexpr version:   1.4.1 (not using Intel's VML/MKL) 
Zlib version:      1.2.3 (in Python interpreter) 
LZO version:       2.04 (Oct 31 2010) 
BZIP2 version:     1.0.6 (6-Sept-2010) 
Blosc version:     1.1.2 (2010-11-04) 
Python version:    2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] 
Byte-ordering:     little 
Detected cores:    4

Ran 4729 tests in 260.580s

OK

---

However, the VITables install keeps failing with the message: *"It seems that PYTables is not installed. Aborting the VITables installation process.*"

Any idea how to fix this?

Thx.
L.